# C# Iterating through data and inserting elements at certain timespan

Tags: c#, jquery, html, user-interface, datetime

I am writing a simple task scheduling app. Currently stuck at some UI. I have few tasks assigned to a user for the current day. The Tasks assigned from 10:00 AM to 01:00 PM and 02:00 PM to 04:00 PM.

I can currently display all the tasks in a div for that time span and the time slots available for new tasks to go in.

What I want to achieve is, Iterate through the tasks and append blocks based on the start and end times.

**I edited the DOM to show what I am after, SAMPLE TIME DISPLAYED.

[image: The blocks should append at their respective start times and have empty blocks between them.]

```
@helper Tasks(int _UserId, DateTime _CurrentDay)
{
//Get all Tasks assigned to the user for _CurrentDay
var _Tasks = Model.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.UserId == _UserId
     && Convert.ToDateTime(t.dtTaskEnd).Date == _CurrentDay.Date);

//Total assigned task hours
int _TotalTaskHrs = 0;

//Loop through all the tasks
foreach (var _Task in _Tasks)
{
    //Current Task Hours
    int _TaskHrs = (Convert.ToDateTime(_Task.dtTaskEnd).Hour - Convert.ToDateTime(_Task.dtTaskStart).Hour);

        <div class="job-task" data-hours="@_TaskHrs">

            <h2>@_Task.TaskName</h2>
            <p>@_Task.TaskCode</p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <p>@_Task.Notes</p>

            <!--edit btn-->
            <span class="job-task-edit" onclick="_ism.tasks.edit(@_Task.TaskId)">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            </span>

        </div>

    _TotalTaskHrs += _TaskHrs;
}

//Unassigned Hours
int _EmptyHrs = 8 - _TotalTaskHrs;
if (_EmptyHrs > 0)
{
        <div class="job-task job-task-empty" data-hours="@_EmptyHrs">
            <!--Add btn-->
            <span class="job-task-edit" onclick="_ism.tasks.add(this,@_UserId)">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
}

}
```

Based on above, this is what I currently have.
[image: This is what I currently have]

The 1st block should start at 10:00 and end at 1:00 PM

So, the blocks should look like.

[Empty 09:00 - 10:00] [TST2 10:00 - 01:00] [Empty 01:00 - 02:00] [TST124 02:00 - 04:00] [Empty 04:00 - 0500]

Any pointers will be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are first adding all the tasks to the day and then filling the rest with empty slots. 
My advice would be to either reconsider the model you are sending to the View, maybe it should already contain empty tasks? or if that's not possible move the if statement into the for-each. Pseudocode for this:

```
int currentHour = 9
foreach (var task in tasks.OrderBy(t=>t.dtTaskStart))
{
  if (task.dsTaskStart > currentHour)
   //fill with empty slot

   //empty slot filled we can now fill the task slot

   currentHour = task.dtTaskEnd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The model only has the tasks assigned, So I have to figure out the empty ones based on that. I tried a few things and then moved my if statement outside, Thanks for the tip, will iterate through every hour and check the start time to see if the task is assigned or not.